# Updating Sections of a Page Upon Filter Change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got a Microsoft MVC "home" page where users can login and view activity against documents they have placed in a CMS--list of what they've uploaded, views over time, downloads over time. There are multiple graphs of activity on the page, with various ways to sort this data, using one "filter" dropdown on the page.

What I want is for the various graphs, lists, etc. to update automatically when the user changes the filter in the dropdown. I could do this by posting the whole page back to the server and getting a brand new page, but I'd like to do it without fully posting back. The way I envision it is that each "section" of the page (graph, list of documents, etc) will detect the filter change and independently do an asynchronous postback to get the new view, with each section updating as soon as the server returns the view.

I also want the home page to be configurable, so the user can determine which views show on the page and where.

What is the best pattern/technological approach for doing this? I can always do a jQuery "changed" event that detects what's on the page and updates each view, but I'd like to avoid a model where I have one big function that updates the whole page and has to be updated when I add new potential views. Better if I can just add the views/controllers, update the DB to indicate that they're there, and then everything takes care of itself automatically on the page according to some set of rules. Just not sure of the best way to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into something like a [SPA framework](https://www.google.com/search?q=single%20page%20application%20framework) .

With [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) for example, you could have different "views" on the page that are binded to javascript objects and update them independently from the rest of the page without too much trouble once you get up and running.